# Xcode 8 template won't generate files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, templates

I am trying to generate files with a custom template but for some reason the files are not generated when I press Create. I have checked the syntax of the objective-C template files and it seems correct.

Is there any obvious reason the files aren't created? Only one out of my 7 templates isn't generating files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem :
I was trying to generate ViewController derivatives. I offered an option to generate ViewControllers as a subclass of UIViewController or UITableViewController.

The problem was my template structure had folders in it named the following way : UIViewControllerObjective-C, UITableViewControllerObjective-C, etc.

Renaming the folders to UIViewController and UITableViewController allowed me to generate the files.

So in case anyone runs into this problem : Check your folder naming!